# volatile jls example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, jls

Should the following code not throw AssertionError on windows 7 x86 jdk 7 (with -ea turned on) per [JLS example for volatile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10323)?

```
public class TestVolatile {
static volatile int i = 0;
static volatile int j = 0;

static void one() {
    i++;
    j++;
    assert (i>=j);
//:"one: i=" + i + " j=" + j;
}
static void two() {
    //System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    assert (i<=j);
    /*
    System.out.print("<i=" + i);
    for (int k = 0; k < 1000000; k++);
    System.out.println(", j=" + j+">");
    */
}
public static final int NUM_WORKERS =  4;

public static void main (String [] args) {
    final Worker [] workers = new Worker[NUM_WORKERS];
    final Thread [] workerThreads = new Thread[NUM_WORKERS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
        Worker w = new Worker(i);
        workers[i] = w;
        workerThreads[i] = new Thread(w,"workerThread_"+i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
        workerThreads[i].start();
    }

}


}

final class Worker implements Runnable {
final int id;
volatile boolean notDone = true;


public Worker(int tid){
    id = tid;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //System.out.println("worker start:" + id);
    try {
        while (notDone) {
            if (id  <  TestVolatile.NUM_WORKERS - 1) {
                TestVolatile.one();
            } else {
                TestVolatile.two();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};
```

Comment: I get an error almost straight away.

Comment: where do you expect error and why? clarify

Comment: I get the error, too, without any delay, and reliably so.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik To be honest I find the wording at the bottom of [example 8.3.1.4-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) a little misleading: *Therefore, the shared value for j is never greater than that for i, because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i before the update to j occurs.*

Comment: It has to be read in the context where there is only one writing thread.

Comment: Yes, here we have N writers and one reader. All bets are off.

Comment: @assylias even for a single writer this statement is wrong, as acknowledged even by the next sentence: “*It is possible, however, that any given invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much greater than the value observed for i,…*”. So j can be greater than i and saying otherwise in the preceding sentence is…misleading at best. There’s [a new Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56285669/2711488) about this and imho, this example should burn in hell…

Answer (score 4):

You have more than 1 thread running `one`. `i` and `j` are volatile, so changes will be visible, however `i++` and `j++` are not atomic operations, and it's very likely that one of the counters won't be properly incremented at some stage:

Let's say i is 5, for example, to show a valid thread interleaving that can throw an AssertionError:

- Thread 1: read i => 5
- Thread 2: read i => 5
- Thread 1: temp = i + 1 => 6
- Thread 2: temp = i + 1 => 6
- Thread 1: write i = temp => 6
- Thread 2: write i = temp => 6
- Thread 1: read j and increment => j = 6
- Thread 2: read j and increment => j = 7

And i and j are out of sync and your assert in `one` will fail.

But it is still possible that a run of the program does not throw an assertion error, despite the presence of that data race: the JLS does not guarantee that your program will run fine, but it does not say that it won't either.

EDIT: one of the guys who wrote the "Threads and Locks" section of the JLS has actually a [post on his blog](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html) about a very similar question. The comments even mention the JLS section you refer to in your question: there is only one writing thread in the JLS example.

Comment: +1 `volatile` doesn't mean all operations on it are atomic, only reading or writing but not both. I believe the example given only works where this is one thread performing the updates.

Comment: I am not sure the example will pass even if only one thread performing the updates. but I totally agree this is a atomic issue in the testing code. thanks guys, this is place is like a real time drill in for JLS.

Comment: another example proof of volatile don't ensure atomicity: http://brooker.co.za/blog/2012/11/13/increment.html